# Число глагола при количественно-именном сочетании

Tags: числительные, сказуемые, единственное-множественное-число, количественно-именное-сочетание

Умира**ют** 2,4 миллиона человек *или* умира**ет** 2,4 миллиона человек?

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, здесь правило про сказуемое при словах *тысяча*, *миллион*, *миллиард* не действует, потому что у нас счетный оборот (слово *миллион* стоит в Р.п.). К сказуемому при счетом обороте применяетя следующий подход:

> Форма единственного числа сказуемого указывает на совместное действие, форма множественного числа – на раздельное совершение действия [[§184. Сказуемое при подлежащем – количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте)]](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_02)

Поэтому возможны варанты в зависимости от контекста (примеры мои):

**От удара атомной бомбы основременно *умирает* 2,4 миллиона человек.**

**В разных уголках планеты в эту минуту *умирают* 2,4 миллиона человек.**

Answer (score 0):

На грамоте.ру: 
Сказуемое при словах тысяча, миллион, миллиард обычно принимает форму подлежащего (единственное число, женский или мужской род). Тысяча человек каждый год отдыхает в этом санатории. Миллион тюльпанов посажен на клумбе.
Возможно, единственное. 
(http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/letters?id=64)